# Alternative to Closure Compiler for properties/function renaming

Tags: javascript, node.js, obfuscation

Currently I am using Google Closure Compiler to minify my code using `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` option.

Unfortunately this features does not rename function/properties.

I have tried to switch to `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` but my code does not conform to those assumptions and the result is unusable.

I would like to know if another minification tools can rename my property/function and make the code more obfuscated.

PS: I actually do not need a lot of optimization from advanced option only the renaming renaming.

So far I have tried uglifyjs with no success.

In the example below, I would need to have `test`, `color`, `name`, 'result' renamed.

```js
    function _App() {}
    _App.prototype = {
      test: function() {
        var color = 'red';
        var name = 'Tom';
        var result = color + name;
        alert(result);
        return result;
      }
    };
    new _App().test();
```

Comment: What's your objetive? To obfuscate your code and make it harder to someone copy it or to just minify it?

Comment: See our JavaScript obfuscator.  It does this just fine. https://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/ECMAScriptObfuscator.html

Comment: @IraBaxter thanks, can I work with that using node/npm or a gulp plugin?